# SQL Query Store qds_async_queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I've recently inherited a SQL Server 2017 instance with performance issues and I've been able to remediate the low hanging fruit. However, one substantial wait still remains.

The Query Store - qds_async_queue seems to be significantly high. But I'm unable to find any meaningful documentation or insight. Microsoft's online description has been at 'TDB' since SQL 2016.

Does anyone have any insight or helpful information about this wait?

Comment: what is experiencing this wait? user queries?

Comment: @MartinSmith this is based entirely off of performance reports. So it's the cumulative wait(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Please note that the official documentation is the official source of information.
2. I took a brief look and this shouldn't be taken as an extreme look from every possible angle.

The wait type is benign as it's a permanent task that which is persisting QDS data in the background. The wait shows up and is incurred while the instance is up and running, it will have more incurred wait if there are items to persist and lower if there are less items to persist.

So, overall, unless there are other issues going on, this wait type can be ignored.